# Extract images like background,Logo and Headings form PSD Files as image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am working on a new project,I never work  on PSD files so having difficulties in extracting images form PSD Files,I want to take background and logo from the images.

Comment: If they are on their own layers, just grab them from the layer they are on. If not, then it all depend on the particular image we're talking about, but will likely take a lot of manual work.

Comment: Open the PSD, press 'v' on the keyboard and drag each layer to a new file and save it out as a JPEG or PNG :)

Answer (score 1):

If they are on their own layers, just grab them from the layer they are on. If not, then it all depend on the particular image we're talking about, but will likely take a lot of manual work means you have to manually select the image or logo and copy or cut it to the project

If you have time then watch this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GBs19HuUFY